# How to update the custom field using trigger in same object?

Tags: trigger

How to solve above solution please give some ideas.

Comment: "salesforce",  please do some effort in your question. Try to explain us your context and what is not clear to you. The question in it's current state is barely understandable and/or very hard to answer due to it's vagueness.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, you may use global static variable to skip self-run trigger.
But it's not the best solution:

```
trigger OppFieldUpdate on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
 if (!GlobalClass.runOnce){
    Opportunity[] updates = new Opporunity[] {};
    for (Opportunity opp: Trigger.new) {
        if (opp.StageName == 'Qualification') {
            updates.add(new Opportunity(Id = opp.Id, Opp.OppStatus__c = 'Won'));
        }
    }
    GlobalClass.runOnce = true;
    update updates;
 }
GlobalClass.runOnce = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseduo code for the same

```
trigger OppFieldUpdate on  Opportunity (before insert, before update) {

for(Opportunity Opp: trigger.new)
{
 if(Opp.StageName == 'Qualification')
 {
 
  Opp.OppStatus__c = 'Won';
 }
}

}
```

However by using Salesforce work flow field update we can achieve the same.

Comment: i need for (after insert, after update)

Comment: trigger myTrigger on Account (after insert) {
Account myAccount=trigger.new[0];
Account updacc=[select id from account where id = :myAccount.id];
updacc.type='Enterprise Customer';
update updacc;
}
 
Salesfore URL for Trigger events, please click on the below link and see the event after update:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you have a strong reason to do this in an "after" trigger and not by any other means:

```
trigger OppFieldUpdate on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
    Opportunity[] updates = new Opporunity[] {};
    for (Opportunity opp: Trigger.new) {
        if (opp.StageName == 'Qualification') {
            updates.add(new Opportunity(Id = opp.Id, Opp.OppStatus__c = 'Won'));
        }
    }
    update updates;
}
```